# Sending 50k Emails a Day Using Sengrid and C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Depending on your experience, is it possible to send 40k emails a day using Sengrid's SMTP relay and C#?

So far I have created a mail queue that sends 1 email per 2 seconds and using Google Workspace email, for now, for 1000 emails a day. However, I'd like to scale to 40k emails a day.

Is it possible to do it with Sengrid's SMTP relay integration? Will my emails get blocked? (Since it is in huge numbers)

How do big companies handle this many number of emails programmatically? (Need to be programmatically because the information that I sent lays in the database)

Thank you

Comment: According to the [FAQ](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/v3-mail-send-faq#are-there-limits-on-how-often-i-can-send-email-and-how-many-recipients-i-can-send-to) the current ratelimit is 10.000 requests per second. So I don't think, 40.000 mails a day will be a problem (if you are on a plan that allows that many emails).

Comment: But maybe you need to "warm up" your account. Ie you cannot immediately start sending 40.000 mails a day. Because for spam-filters this may be a sign of spam-attack and the sender may get blacklisted. Also you have to keep an eye on bounces. Because most of the providers will suspend your account if they detect many bounces or other suspicious activity to protect their service from getting blacklisted ...

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Here's [a guide on how to bulk email with C#](https://www.twilio.com/blog/bulk-email-with-csharp-and-dotnet).
However, this doesn't touch on the deliverability side of things. You need to include a way to unsubscribe, make sure your emails are relevant and wanted, have a dedicated IP and protect its reputation, etc. Check out this other [bulk email resource for those things](https://sendgrid.com/resource/bulk-email-guide/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sendgrid to send well over 40k emails a day. I think that the limitation is on 20MB per email.

Regarding spam, you should have no problems if you validate your account and register your provider and all. Sendgrid has some steps required from your side to prevent this from happening.

One thing to note us that there is the SMTP server integration, the UI and the C# Api. They are not the same thing. If you are using C#, the api is for you.

I am not affiliated with Sendgrid.